# Passport.JS, how can you get all logged in account?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport.js

Title should be self explanatory I guess. At this moment I track manually currently logged in account in an array. However, if the server is restarted, while the account is still logged in in client, the array will reset. So my tracking to currently logged in account is lost.

If there is a better method I would like to know.

Comment: You can use session like redis-session or other session to store manual info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use session like redis-session or other session to store manual info. When you need to clear then just clear your session.

Comment: I use MongoDB. What I am thinking is how to detect log out if the browser was cookie/history reset instead of using proper log out?

Comment: check is session value is available or not, if not available(session/ cookie is deleted of not available) then work for login.